# Как сделать LEFT JOIN через INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle

Задача несколько творческая. В Impala из Oracle драйвер не спускает внешние соединения таблиц (LEFT JOIN). То есть он в импале выполнет запрос обеих частей соединения и джойнить будет уже в оракле, получив результаты обоих запросов по сети. UNION тоже не спускается. Поэтому нужно придумать как сделать левый джон, но через внутренний (например, в случае если в правой таблице не находится нужной строки, то джойнилось бы на какую-нибудь заглушку). Например относительно рабочий вариант:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_a
  JOIN (select col_a, col_b from table_b
        union all
        select null col_a, null col_b from dual) t
    ON (<<настоящее_условие_соединения>> AND NOT (col_a is null AND col_b is null))
    OR (NOT <<настоящее_условие_соединения>> AND (col_a is null AND col_b is null)) -- то есть реализация XOR
```

Но как я сказал, UNION использовать тоже нельзя. Был бы благодарен за любые идеи по обходу ограничения.

Comment: Есть еще вариант просто добавить строку в table_b (заглушку) и использовать также как здесь использую дополнительную строку. Но вариант тоже не прокатил - нельзя добавить искусственную строку во вторую таблицу.

Comment: Сделать в БД view с нужным union и джоинить ее

Comment: Или, если условия ON самого left join всегда постоянны вообще сделать в БД view с готовым left join, что бы в основной выборке оно выглядело как одна таблица

Comment: А как эта чехарда относится к подзапросам? которые без UNION и с честным INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Mike Да, вероятно придется делать вьюху с уже готовым левым джойном на стороне импалы, но хотелось бы этого избежать. Хотябы потому что регулярно возникает необходимость джойнить слева разные таблицы, но на каждый кейс представление не насоздаешь. Хорошо бы иметь обходное решение.

Comment: @Akina я так понял, вы тоже обращаетесь к Mike

Comment: Неправильно. Это именно к Вам вопрос. А то лефтджойн низя, юнион низя... что можно-то?

Comment: @Akina ну вы примерно уловили моё эмоциональное состояние, да) А еще нельзя is null, сугубо оракловые функции (их в импалу не отправишь - будет делать на стороне оракла), функции импалы (их уже сам оракл не поймет) и в целом там есть ворох нюансов у драйвера (например, в селект-лист не стоит добавлять константы - лучше обернуть внешним запросом и добавить уже в нём). Самый безопасный способ - использовать универсальный SQL без UNION, без LEFT JOIN и без is null (но тут еще туда-сюда, можно вместо нулов использовать 'N\D' в таблицах.